# Find a document using a matching adjacent field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to find documents that match an initial value, but using an adjacent value... I know this is not clear (and probably why I do not find solutions to this) so here you have an examples collection :

```
{
  "id": 123456,
  "login": "nvh",
},
{
  "id": 789012,
  "login": "notnvh",
},
{
  "id": 123456,
  "login": "notnvh",
}
```

I'd like to find all documents where the ID is 123456 since my initial search value would be "nvh" like : `mongo.collection('collection').find({ login: 'nvh'})` and it outputs these two documents since on of them had 'nvh' as login and it found all matching ids

```
{
  "id": 123456,
  "login": "nvh",
},
{
  "id": 123456,
  "login": "notnvh",
}
```

Maybe would it be too complicated or do I think way too far of Mongo's capabilities ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, "login" is unique but id is not?

Comment: All IDs are bound to a user, but each user can change it's "login". This is why I can search for "login" that I know in advance but not the ID. Let's say my query is `login : "nvh"` then I'd find all documents that have ID 123456 since at least one of them has `login : "nvh"` in it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this in two steps:

```
async function findByLogin(login) {
  const record = await mongo.collection('collection').findOne({ login })
  return mongo.collection('collection').find({ id: record.id })
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! Didn't actually think to make it in two times. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NVH, great! maybe you could upvote the answer, if it was useful

Comment: I would have liked to but it tells me that I need at least 15 reputation!

Comment: oh :) ok, no worries then